# JavaScript isolate hash value

Tags: javascript, hash

Kind of a follow up to a question from yesterday. I have a hash that changes values and need to isolate the second half. The code below DOES work, but needs to return false if there isn't a value because I'm using `if (val.length){}` later on and it is currently always true. So, to demonstrate:

```
var hash = window.location.hash,
    page = hash.split('=')[0],
    val  = hash.substr(hash.indexOf('=') + 1);

    console.log(hash,page,val);

localhost/#work
console returns: #work, #work, #work

localhost/#work=misery
console returns: #work=misery, #work, misery
```

I'd like it to return:

```
localhost/#work
console returns: #work, #work, (no value for val)

localhost/#work=misery
console returns: #work=misery, #work, misery
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same approach you have for page:

```
var hash = window.location.hash,
    values = hash.split("="),
    page = values[0],
    val  = values[1];

console.log(hash,page,val);

localhost/#work
console returns: #work, #work, undefined

localhost/#work=misery
console returns: #work, #work, misery
```

P.S.
I will suggest to you to add the JavaScript tag and maybe remove the jQuery ones, because it's a question totally unrelated to jQuery.

Comment: Good point. My heads too far in it, no longer a human. So this works as you explain, returning undefined, but now val.length throws an error in my console when it's undefined (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined). Should I use an alternate method to .length()? I'll I'm trying to identify is: IF there is a value in addition to the hash, THEN blah.

Comment: Because `val` is undefined, you can simple have: `if (val) { /* do something */ }`. Notice that this will work for all falsy value, it means in your case even if you have `localhost/#work=` (so with 'equal' sign but without value).

Comment: Notice that this is useful also when you have a scenario where you need to do different actions if the value is given, but is empty, and if the value is not given at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some logic to check if there is a value

```
var hash = window.location.hash,
    values = hash.split("="),
    page = values[0],
    val  = values[1]?values[1]:'';//you can use if (val.length){} to check if ther is a value

console.log(hash,page,val);
```